# LINQ Count ocurrences

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to write a LINQ query to count number of ocurrences of a type.

Something like this:

```
 var qry = from c in db.XBLRegionalContents
    where c.PublishDate <= DateTime.Today
    group c by c.ContentId into grouped
    select new FeaturedViewModel { XBLRegionalContent = db.XBLRegionalContents.Find(grouped.Key), RegionCount = grouped.Count() };
```

But something is not right. I want to show the `XBLRegionalContents` object with a count of how many regions it has on the db.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code for XBLRegionalContent

```
public class XBLRegionalContent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ContentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContentId")]
    public virtual XBLContent Content { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
    public virtual XBLRegion Region { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: Each regional content is shown with count = 1. I'm trying to group all regions by the same ContentId and count them while showing the object himself.

Comment: If you skip the `db.XBLRegionalContents.Find(grouped.Key)` and only return the Key, do you still get the same count? (you should) In that case you should verify your data.

Comment: Doesn't work, because grouped.Key is a string, not a XBLRegionalContent. Cannot convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

This is the solution:

```
var qry = from c in db.XBLRegionalContents
    where c.PublishDate <= DateTime.Today
    group c by c.ContentId into grouped
    select new FeaturedViewModel {
        XBLRegionalContent = grouped.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentId == grouped.Key),
        RegionCount = grouped.Count()
    };
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with your `Find` statement.  The `Find()` should take a predicate that returns true or false.  You're just passing in a string, so I guess that's just looping through each item in your collection.

I took some liberties with your sample code and put together a small example with LinqPad to demonstrate using Find.  You should get a contentID of "a" with a count of 2 and everything else has a count of 1.

(The Dump() method is specific to LinqPad -- it just prints out all properties of an object or collection.)

```
void Main()
{
    var XBLRegionalContents = new List<XBLRegionalContent>(){
        new XBLRegionalContent { contentID = "a", ID = "aa" },
        new XBLRegionalContent { contentID = "b", ID = "bb" },
        new XBLRegionalContent { contentID = "a", ID = "cc" },
        new XBLRegionalContent { contentID = "d", ID = "dd" }
    };

    XBLRegionalContents.Dump();

    var qry = from c in XBLRegionalContents
        group c by c.contentID into grouped
        select new { xbl = XBLRegionalContents.Find(x => x.contentID == grouped.Key), regionCount = grouped.Count() };

    qry.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class XBLRegionalContent{
    public string contentID {get;set;}
    public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

Hope this helps.  Let me know if there are other questions.  Good luck!

Comment: doesn't work because Find() recieves params object[], not a lambda expression. Anywah, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.  I didn't notice you were using EF.  What's your primary key for XBLRegionalContent?

Comment: It is a multiple PK of "ContentId" and "RegionId".